# Android support jinitiator

Tags: android

I'm starting to work on a project for my Collage . The project is to take the collage website and make an android app that loads the website in the app .

the website use jinitiator for registration and i should be able to register via mobile .

does android support jinitiator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it out but jinitiator has been obsolete since 2008 and oracle itself says there is no need for it anymore.

Legacy technology integration might pose some serious incompatibility problems for you. I would rather suggest that your college upgrade their registration system. I feel safe in assuming they need it badly.